# Pass colors from CSS to Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am defining my theme colors as variables in my CSS file. Then I want to use the same colors in my JavaScript (it takes values from a database and generates graphs). I do not want to specify the colors again in the JS. Can I load a list of colors from the CSS, and if so, how?

CSS file:

```
/* http://www.colorhunt.co/c/43601 */
:root{
    --maincolor: #113f67;
    --secondcolor: #34699a;
    --thirdcolor: #408ab4;
    --fourthcolor: #65c6c4; 
}
```

Comment: Why not reverse it and set the colors from javascript?

Comment: @Bálint because these are the main colors for the entire site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the variables to the body, then read out the styles using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

`var bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);`

This returns an object of all styles defined on the body, now you can retrace it using [getPropertyValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration)

`var varName = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue('--var-name');`

In which varName now contains your variable, to do this for all colors:

```
var bodyStyles = window.getComputedStyle(document.body);
var colors = ['--maincolor', '--secondcolor', '--thirdcolor', '--fourthcolor'];
var colorValues = [];

for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    colorValues.push({'name': colors[i], 'hex': bodyStyles.getPropertyValue(colors[i])})
}
```

Comment: I tweaked your solution a bit because I like names more than indices, so ended up using a dictionary instead of a list: 
colorValues[colors[i]] = bodyStyles.getPropertyValue(colors[i]);